# C# isolate elements of an array in a string with escape character \

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, replace, escaping

I've several arrays such as:

```
string[] sArTrigFunctions = {"sin", "cos", "tan", "sinh", "cosh", "tanh", "cot", "sec", "csc", "arcsin", "arccos", "arctan", "coth", "sech", "csch"};
string[] sArGreek = { "alpha", "beta", "chi", "delta", "Delta", "epsi", "varepsilon", "eta", "gamma", "Gamma", "iota", "kappa", "lambda", "Lambda", "lamda", "Lamda", "mu", "nu", "omega", "Omega", "phi", "varphi", "Phi", "pi", "Pi", "psi", "Psi", "rho", "sigma", "Sigma", "tau", "theta", "vartheta", "Theta", "upsilon", "xi", "Xi", "zeta" };
string sArBinOp = {"lt","gt","eq","neq",.....}; etc.
```

These array elements are used in a text file where these are mixed with each other or with other content of the file. For example: `sintheta`, a`lt`c.
I want to escape these array elements in the file with `\` so `sintheta` becomes `\sin\theta` and `altc` becomes `a\ltc`. A simple string.replace(...) does not work. For example if I run the following `foreach` loop on `sArTrigFunctions` array and then on `sArGreek` array, it will replace `sintheta` in the file to `\sinth\eta`. If I rearrange the order of `sArGreek` elements in descending order by length of elements so theta comes before eta, then the following code will first change `sintheta` to `\sin\theta` and then to `\sin\th\eta`. Likewise, running the following code on `sArBinOp` array will replace `sindelta` to  `sinde\lta` or if we first run the following code on `sArGreek` and then on `sArGreek` the `sindelta` gets changed to `\sin\de\lta`:

```
foreach (string s in sArGreek)
{
    strfileContent = strfileContent.Replace(s, "\\" + s);
}
```

**Question**: How can we programmatically make it so that during the replace process if an array element is inside another array element of any array don't escape it with `\`. For example don't escape `eta` in `sintheta` but do so in `sineta`. Likewise, don't escape `lt` in `sindelta` but do so in `altc`
**Note**: The array elements in the file are not not necessarily separated by a space, i.e. `sintheta` is not written as `sin theta` otherwise we could use [C# Regex Word Boundary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx#WordBoundary) to achieve this using the code like the following, for example:

```
foreach (string s in sArGreek)
{
    strfileContent = Regex.Replace(strfileContent, "\\b" + s + "\\b", "\\" + s + " ");
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want to replace the 1st occurrence of the match and not every occurrence.  Am I correct?

Comment: @Amit Your code does not replace sintheta with \sin\theta. I should have been more clear in my example. I updated by original post by adding an additional array `sArTrigFunctions`. So, we run your code on this array and then on  `sArGreek`. I tested your code on input `sintheta and coseta with tantheta` by running your Regex first on `sArTrigFunctions` and then, on the returning string, running your Regex on `sArGreek` I get the desired result `\sin\theta and \cos\eta with \tan\theta`. Let me test your code on many other arrays and see if it works on all. If all passes, your comment is answer.

Comment: @jdweng Not that. I should have been more clear in my example. I've added an additional array `sArTrigFunctions` to my  original post and referring it my post. Please also see my comment to @Amit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression replace.

First you need to construct your Regex from the input arrays. The structure of the expression is:

```
term1|term2|term3|t4|t5
```

Meaning, all the terms in a single string, separated by "|" (regex OR), sorted by descending term length. This is important since we want to capture longer terms when possible, and fallback to shorter terms when needed.

To do that, a little LINQ query comes handy:

```
Regex re = new Regex(String.Join("|", (
    from s in sArTrigFunctions.Union(sArGreek).Union(sArBinOp)
    orderby s.Length descending
    select s).ToArray()));
```

We're creating a single enumerable from all our arrays, then sorting by length, and joining to a single string. This is used to create a `Regex` object.

Then it's a simple replace:

```
re.Replace("sintheta altc", "\\$&");
```

`"\\$&"` means replace the entire match (single term at a time) with itself prefixed with a backslash.

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QNScqg)

Comment: Thank you for smart solution, it works. A good example to test: The input `sintheta and altc test secdelta coseta with tantheta` gets replaced with desired output: `\sin\theta and a\ltc test \sec\delta \cos\eta with \tan\theta`