# Replace first column value with second column value using Regex in jagged array

Tags: c#, regex, jagged-arrays

In an input string, I want to use the following [Jagged Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca(v=vs.120).aspx) to replace the first column value with the second column prepended with `\`. For example, `a<=bTestc<e` becomes `a\lebTestc\lte`. How can I achieve this **programatically**? I'm using a Regex pattern defined below by concatenating all first column elements of the jagged array, using the `|` (Regex "OR") separator between each element. I've concatenated the elements by taking the elements in the order of largest length to the shortest length so that if the shorter element is contained within the larger element it does not get replaced [Ref: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34484688/1232087). I'm using .NET 4.5.2

```
string[][] sSymb = { new string[] { "!=", "ne" }, new string[] { "lt=", "leq" }, new string[] { "<", "lt" }, new string[] { ">", "gt" }, new string[] { "<=", "le" }, new string[] { "gt=", "geq" }, new string[] { ">=", "ge" }, new string[] { "!in", "notin" }, new string[] { "sub", "subset" }, new string[] { "sup", "supset" } };
string sPattern = "gt=|!in|sub|sup|!=|<=|lt|>=|<|>";
Regex regex = new Regex(sPattern);
string st = regex.Replace("a<=bcd<e", "\\$&"); //this prepends the first column element of array with \ . I need to replace the first column element with \ + second column element 
Console.WriteLine(st);
```

Comment: Hi! I added in an example of how to achieve what you're after using the jagged array; but I think the ordered dictionary is a more elegant solution. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be using the [overload for replace which allows you to pass in a match evaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string st = regex.Replace("a<=bcd<e", match =>
{
    var matchingSymbol = sSymb.FirstOrDefault(symbol => symbol[0] == match.Value);
    if (matchingSymbol == null)
        throw new Exception("Could not find symbol to exchange.");

    return string.Concat("\\",  matchingSymbol[1]);
});
```

Also - do you have to use a jagged array? It would be much easier using a dictionary.

**Edit**: Just took another look at your keys to be matched and realised that order will be very important here. You'll need to make sure your entries to be replaced is ordered from most specific to least specific (otherwise the regex engine will match "<" when it could have matched "<=").

In which case, an Ordered Dictionary would probably be the best way to achieve this:

```
var sSymb = new System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
{
    { "<=", "le" },
    { ">=", "ge" },
    { "!=", "ne" },
    { "<", "lt" },
    { ">", "gt" },
    { "gt=", "geq" }, 
    { "lt=", "leq" },
    { "!in", "notin" }, 
    { "sub", "subset" }, 
    { "sup", "supset" } 
};

var sPattern = sSymb.Keys
    .Cast<string>()
    .Aggregate((left, right) => string.Format("{0}|{1}", left, right));

Regex regex = new Regex(sPattern);
string st = regex.Replace("a<=bcd<e", match => string.Format("\\{0}", sSymb[match.Value]));
Console.WriteLine(st);
```

Comment: I agree that your ordered dictionary solution is a better solution. To me the most important part of your solution - `that helped me most` - was how to use the dictionary value based on the matched key. The order of collection elements in your both solutions is important. Question: In my case will sortedList be a better choice than ordered dictionary?

Comment: No, ordered dictionary is better as the lookup time for elements is (generally) faster, since a dictionary uses the object hash to retrieve its elements.

Comment: Also, unless you implement a custom comparer, the sorted list will order the items in the wrong order - `"<"` will be sorted before `"<="`. So if you're using the sorted list to build up your regex pattern automatically, it will never find instances of `"<="` (same for `">"` versus `">="`)

Comment: The difference with an `OrderedDictionary` is that it maintains items _in the order they were inserted_, rather than in their "natural" sorted order.